# Error when installing NUnit 3.9 in Visual Studio 13 with NuGet

Tags: selenium, nunit

I am trying to install NUnit 3.9 in Visual Studio 13 Professional, but I am facing the below mentioned error while installing:

```
'NUnit' already has a dependency defined for 'NETStandard.Library'.
```

How do I solve this issue?

[image]

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: @DebanjanB, this is a legitimate .NET question and one that quite a few devs run into with various packages. With the move to .NET Core, older versions of Visual Studio and NuGet stop working. Figuring out which versions are compatible can be difficult. I wouldn't be surprised if this issue was a duplicate and it probably belongs on the NUnit GitHub issue boards, so I will give you that much 

Answer (score 2):

This error is often caused by the fact that your version of NuGet is too old. Try updating NuGet.

NUnit's most recent NuGet packages include .NET Standard builds, which mean NuGet client version 2.12 or later is required. From the next version of NUnit, you'll get a more helpful error message for this.

Comment: I am having NuGet 2.120.817 version but i don't know why this issues exist

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you running? I think only VS2012 with at least update 1 is supported.

Comment: Now its working after upgrade the nuget version. Appreciate your help

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot upgrade Visual Studio to a newer version that includes newer versions of NuGet, you can install NUnit 3.5.0 which doesn't include .NET Standard. You can select the older versions from a dropdown in the user interface, or install from the Package Manager Console.

```
Install-Package NUnit -Version 3.5.0
```